# MVC2 problem with uk pound symbol in ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The following ActionLink:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Home £", "Index")%>
```

Generates the markup:

```
<a href="/">Home &#194;&#163;</a>
```

Which looks like this:

Home Â£

I take it that this is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot seem to duplicate this on my machine however the theory is, if your browsers character encoding is not the same as the document encoding then you may recieve this type of error. Character encoding is typically set by the user of the browser. You can try and force the content encoding to UTF-8, by doing the following:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization
      fileEncoding="utf-8"
      requestEncoding="utf-8"
      responseEncoding="utf-8"
      culture="en-GB"
      uiCulture="en-GB"
    />
   ...
```

or on the page by doing this:

```
<%@ Page RequestEncoding="utf-8" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

Comment: You are correct. Specifically, the fileEncoding="utf-8" attribute fixes it. Not sure why I have the mismatch though.